# The usage of "what else"

Tags: idioms

Source: https://autos.yahoo.com/news/russian-driver-shakes-off-massive-accident-nothing-happenned-120025524.html

> Think you’ve got good reflexes? See how you’d stack up against this Volkswagen Touareg driver in – **what else** – another bowel-clenching Russian dashcam video.

How do you understand the expression **what else** used in the way it's used in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means approximately *What else would you expect it to be?*  That is, *all* driving videos of the sort that make your bowels clench in horror are Russian dashcam videos.

Note that the author's comment after the video is

> If it’s remotely possible of happening, it has already been recorded on a Russian dashcam.